# LibreOffice can't use keyboard shortcuts while typing in any language but English?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, libreoffice, keyboard-layout, language-support

I'm using libreoffice under Ubuntu 13.10 . Using English as main language Arabic as another language.  When writing English I can use keyboard shortcut like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.

When starting to write in Arabic I can't use all these shortcuts any more . I must change language to English again just to do cut - paste stuff !

Thank u in advance .

Answer (score 6):

It is a bug, see here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libreoffice/+bug/1246583

But it has now been **fixed** in the new **LibreOffice beta 4.2** version. It can be downloaded and installed  from the Libreoffice website.

However, I still have the same issue in UBUNTU 13.10 with Apache openoffice 4.0.1.
No fix there yet.

Comment: I still see this issue with LO 4.4.2.2 (on Lubuntu 15.04). Are you sure?

Answer (score 5):

I have the Same problem in Persian language. it seems libreoffice can't detect the character `A, C, V` etc. which are following the `Ctrl`
http://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/24338/keyboard-shortcuts-on-libreoffice-41-wont-act-when-i-change-the-language/

Now I've found that if you remove the following packages, the problem will be OK.

```
libreoffice-gtk libreoffice-gnome
```

Comment: This works for me, but now libreoffice-writer looks like ms-word in windows-95, and it's window has transparent region at top when maximized. Ubuntu 13.10 here.

Comment: yes, i have this problem in persian language too. thanks a lot

Comment: Doesn't work for me (with Hebrew, LO 4.4.2.2 and Lubuntu 15.04).