# How to enable Paste function with Ctrl-Shift-V in Ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: command-line, keyboard, shortcut-keys, libreoffice

I have very simple question after installation/upgrade to 13.10. Seems that Paste function (or Paste without formatting) keyboard shortcut does not work in 13.10. It was a very convenient way to paste non-formatted text in LibreOffice or in the Terminal. Thus, my question is:

How can I enable Paste function with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> in Ubuntu 13.10?

Comment: May I please ask you to copy something, then open a terminal and try Ctrl-Shift-V there? It will help determine if the problem involves your DE (Desktop Environment).  Please also test Shift-Insert and middle-mouse-button-click, both in the CLI (Command Line Interface) and in the DE.

Comment: Thanks for prompt reaction on my question:
I found out that the only keyboard combination, which works for me is a Shift-Insert in LibreOffice (in LibreOffice it pastes FORMATTED text). Unfortunately, other suggested shortcuts didn't work. I am using a laptop Dell E5420 (keyboard: US International).

Comment: Does Ctrl-V paste with or without formatting in Libre* ?

Comment: Ctrl-V preserves formatting in LibreOffice, the same occurs when I paste formatted text in Gmail window (in Firefox).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are using ENGLISH (US) keyboard layout. Otherwise see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/363526/libreoffice-cant-use-keyboard-shortcuts-while-typing-in-any-language-but-englis/391116#391116).

For me it **works with Ctrl+RIGHT_Shift+V** in all keyboard layouts Ubuntu 13.10.

The same in LIBREOFFICE + OPENOFFICE

It does NOT work with  Ctrl+LEFT_Shift+V because Ctrl+LEFT_shift is assigned to a different combination in keyboard settings. Check your settings. See here for my example:
[image: url]

Comment: Thank you for hint. It works fine in Ubuntu 13.10. Meanwhile, I tested Ctrl-Shift-V in LinuxMint 16, it is functioning correctly in LibreOffice 4.1.3.2.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, you need to:

```
sudo apt-get purge libreoffice-gtk libreoffice-gnome
```

You'll get a somewhat ugly UI, but functional keyboard shortcuts!