# Using russian layout shortcuts Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V do not work

Tags: 13.10, keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I've read many online resources, but got nothing.

Shortcuts like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> | <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> | <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> don't work in most of applications when I switch to Russian layout, but when I switch back to English (US) everything works ok. -- It is terrible!

I tried to move English layout to the top of layouts' order, but it doesn't help.

[image]

Comment: Could you give some examples of applications where it fails? I just tried this by switching between Greek (which also has a different alphabet and should have the same problem) and English and Ctrl+X/C/V  worked fine in firefox. Other shortcuts will fail but these tend to work.

Comment: Only FF and Chrome works correctly, the other programs like Phpstorm, nautilus, skype, kingsoft office etc doesn't deal with russia layout

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu and which desktop environment are you using? That looks like Unity, is that correct? I tried on Ubuntu 13.10 and Unity and the shortcuts worked fine in nautilus (version 3.8.2) as well.

Comment: Sorry for the mistakes: nautilus works fine. Kingsoft office and Phpstorm only. I was able to affect)). Because of nothing was copied I was pasted nothing into other programs..

Comment: This is a confirmed bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/1226962 . It looks like a fix was released, so try to update your system.

Comment: Yes, that makes more sense, then it sounds like a bug in those specific programs. Have a look [here](http://askubuntu.com/q/363526/85695) for a similar bug in libreoffice.

Comment: Do people test their products when they release it? I think, don't!

Comment: Well, Ubuntu is different from Windows. For example, when you type [Ctrl]+[X] in russian layout, the system thinks you type [Ctrl]+[Ч]. It's not a bug, it's a feature :P

Comment: If it is cool feature may be it is need to add option wherewith it can be easily disabled?)

Comment: @TimurFayzrakhmanov Is solved your problem? I use 14.04 but this problem exist.

Comment: @MahdiParsa Hello now I'm using 14.04.1, but it doesn't matter in solving layout problem. I solve my problem by using another software as far as possible. For example, I used Kingsoft Office and because of the problem I switched to LibreOffice. However Phpstorm 7 still makes me to switch layout if I want to copy/paste/cut

Comment: I had the same problem and I solved it using following instructions:

1) sudo add-apt-repository ppa:attente/java-non-latin-shortcuts
2) sudo apt-get update
3) sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

Hope it will help you too.

Comment: Sigh, running into the same issue some years later ... finding a closed question on AskUbuntu. Classic!